# Convert `std::any` to `std::variant`

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

There's not much to be done with a `std::any` (except store it) until its contained type is known or suspected. Then it can be queried (`type()`) or cast (`any_cast`). But what about when instead of one type there is a need to deal with multiple types? In this case a solution can be to convert it to `std::variant`.

E.g. An API provides `std::any` objects, but only a finite set of types is required and the objects need to be stored in a container (vector, tree etc.).

How can `std::any` be converted to `std::variant`?

---

Disclaimer: `std::any` is mainly intended to be used in library code where its purpose is to replace `void *` in some clever templates and type erasures. As with any new thing `std::any` can be overused and misused. Please think twice if `std::any` is the right solution for your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code takes a `std::any` object along with a list of types and converts the object to `std::variant` or throws `std::bad_any_cast` if the stored type is not one of the given types.

```
#include <any>
#include <variant>
#include <optional>
#include <typeinfo>

template <class... Args>
auto any_to_variant_cast(std::any a) -> std::variant<Args...>
{
    if (!a.has_value())
        throw std::bad_any_cast();

    std::optional<std::variant<Args...>> v = std::nullopt;

    bool found = ((a.type() == typeid(Args) && (v = std::any_cast<Args>(std::move(a)), true)) || ...);

    if (!found)
        throw std::bad_any_cast{};

    return std::move(*v);
}
```

Example usage:

```
auto test(const std::any& a)
{
    auto v = any_to_variant_cast<int, std::string>(a);

    std::visit([](auto val) { std::cout << val << std::endl; }, v);
}
```

[Code on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/etYRNo)

---

Some explanations:

`std::optional<std::variant<Args...>>` is used because `std::variant<Args...>` [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant) constructs the variant holding the value-initialized value of the first alternative and requires the first alternative to be default constructible.

```
   ((a.type() == typeid(Args) && (v = std::any_cast<Args>(std::move(a)), true)) || ...)
//   ------------------------     -------------------------------------  
//          type_check                             any_cast
```

This is a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). I've renamed some of the subexpression to be easier to explain. With the renaming the expression becomes:

```
// ((type_check && (any_cast, true)) || ...)
```

- if `type_check` is `false` then:

  - `(any_cast, true)` is not evaluated due to the short circuit of `&&`
  - `(type_check && (any_cast, true))` evaluates to `false`
  - the next op in the fold expression is evaluated
- if `type_check` is `true` then:

  - `(any_cast, true)` is evaluated:

    - `any_cast` is evaluated. The variant get the value from the any object.
    - `any_cast` result is discarded
    - `true` is evaluated
    - `(any_cast, true)` evaluates to `true`
  - `(type_check && (any_cast, true))` evaluates to `true`
  - the rest of the fold is not evaluated due to the short circuit of `||`
  - the whole expression (the fold) evaluates to `true`
- if no `type_check` evaluates to `true` then the whole expression (the fold) evaluates to `false`